# ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add don't show Text To Display

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I came across an unexpected behavior of the command ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add in Excel VBA

If I use the following code

```
Sub Hyperlinks_Test()
Dim Link As String
Dim Text As String
Link = "www.google.com"
Text = "Link To Google"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Cells(2, 2).Value = 3.14
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(2, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:=Link, TextToDisplay:=Text
Cells(3, 2).Value = #3/31/2023#
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(3, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:=Link, TextToDisplay:=Text
Cells(4, 2).Value = "String"
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(4, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:=Link, TextToDisplay:=Text
End Sub
```

I obtain correct result just in cell (4,2) i.e. the cell shows title "Link To Google" and contains hyperlink to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). If the cell contains a number or a date before I used the command "ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add", the result is the number or the date instead of title "Link To Google" but correctly contains hyperlink to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBEe.jpg)

Is it bug in ".Hyperlinks.Add" command or I do an error in using the function?
Thank you.

Comment: Possibly, `TextToDisplay:=Cells(4, 2).value`

Answer (score 0):

This is how excel works it is not a bug.
When a cell has a number value or "text" like number value then texttodisplay does not work.Try in excel to insert manually a hyperlink in these cells and you will see that text to display is not enabled

In this case we add the hyperlink and then change the cell's value